# Flutter: Not able to use nested models with Entities. (Entities, Models, Equatable, Flutter, Dart, json_serializable,Json Serialization)

Tags: flutter, dart, model, entities, json-serializable

I have two file for a single data i.e Entity and Model. To separate the entire logic from each other and to follow best practices.
Whenever I am trying to use nested Entities and parsing through @JsonSerializable it's showing me error.

Note: I have tried @JsonConverter too. It's not working.

I'm sure I'm missing something over there but can't get it.
**Please help.**

test_entity.dart

```
class TestEntity extends Equatable {
final String id;
final List<AddressEntity> address;

const TestEntity({
required this.id,
required this.address,
});
@override
List<Object?> get props => [
    id,
    address,
  ];
}
```

test_model.dart

```
part 'test_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class TestModel extends TestEntity {
const TestModel({
required String id,
required List<AddressModel> address,
}) : super(
      id: id,
      address: address,
    );
factory TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  _$TestModelFromJson(json);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestModelToJson(this);
}
```

address_entity.dart

```
class AddressEntity extends Equatable {
 final String id;
 final String title;

const AddressEntity({
 required this.id,
 required this.title,
});
@override
List<Object?> get props => [
    id,
    title,
  ];
}
```

address_model.dart

```
part 'address_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class AddressModel {
 final String id;
 final String title;

 AddressModel({
  required this.id,
  required this.title,
 });

 factory AddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$AddressModelFromJson(json);

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddressModelToJson(this);
 }
```

When I use AddressModel instead AddressEntity

[Here is the Snap of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6oY2.png)

[Also This Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWAMZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Any property of a JsonSerializeble class should have its own `fromJson()` constructor. Your TestEntity class has the `List<AddressEntity>` as a property, but `AddressEntity` has no such constructor.

To fix this, just implement `fromJson()` constructor and `toJson()` method for the `AddressEntity` class. There is no difference if you make it by hand or with the help of the JsonSerializeble generator.

Comment: What if I use List<AddressModel> instead List<AddressEntity> because it already having that constructor. but still getting same error,

Comment: as I don't wanna mix up the Entities with the Models, because models are having `fromJson()` and `toJson()` while entities don't.

Comment: What error is it btw? :)

Comment: I see now. The problem has nothing to do with JsonSerializeble. You are trying to pass List<AddressModel> to constructor that expects List<AddressEntity>. You can't do that since AddressModel is not a subtype of AddressEntity.